# importing Cocoalibspotify

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-libraries, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm trying to import the cocoalibspotify into my Xcode project. https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify

However I am completly lost to what files need to be imported and how. I'm still a beginner and the sparse info on the spotify website doesn't really help me. I did manage to run the Simple Player sample project though and I tried looking at what files are imported. But I didn't get very far with this.

I tried importing the following files that come with the zip by dragging these into my project:

- CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library.xcodeproj
- CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library-Prefix.pch
- SPLoginResources.bundle
- CocoaLibSpotify iOS Test Container (folder)
- View Controllers (folder)

after doing that however, my project simply won't compile anymore.
I'm getting all kinds of errors. I'm guessing these are related to setting the wrong target???

[image]

the website does mention a couple more instructions for iOS when you scroll down on the page https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify

I did manage to import the frameworks but the other stuff is beyond me.

So if anyone is willing to guide me through this, that would be great!

---

EDIT:

I think I'm getting closer. I've created a ".a" file by opening the "CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library.xcodeproj " and making a build. then I import the resulting libCocoaLibSpotify.a file and also a folder called "include" which has a lot of header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *only* need to include the `CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library.xcodeproj` file in your project.

Once you've done that, make sure CocoaLibSpotify is added in the "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary with Libraries" build phases of your project by clicking the '+' button in each of those phases and choosing it from the list.

Other than that, make sure you closely follow the instructions in the "Building - iOS" section of CocoaLibSpotify's README.markdown file and you'll be set.